# Why is not the control moving to the script method "checkExistence()"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am doing a file upload program in which i am using ajax call to check whether any file exists with the same name.

Here is the code

> jsp page

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "form" uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>File Upload Example</title>
     <script src="/AjaxWithSpringMVC2Annotations/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function checkExistence() {
                var name = $('#file').val();
                File f=new File(name);
                 var filename=f.getOriginalFileName();
                 document.write(filename);
                 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/FileController/fileexists",
                data: "filename=" + filename,
                  success: function(response){
                if(response==0)
                {
                 ch="zero";
                    document.fileform.choice.value=ch;
                    document.fileform.submit();
                }
            else if(response==1)
                {
                 alertchoice=alert("File already exists !! Do you want me to overwrite it ?");
                if(alertchoice==true || alertchoice.equals(true))
                    {
                    ch="one";
                document.fileform.choice.value=ch;
                document.fileform.submit();
                    }
                else {
                    ch="two";
                    alert("Upload suspended as requested by the user ");
                } }
                  },
                  error: function(e){
                alert('Error: ' + e);
                }
                });
                }
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;color:Tomato"> 
<br>
<br>
<center><form name="fileform" action="savefile" method = "POST" modelAttribute = "fileUpload"
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         Please select a file to upload : 
         <input type = "file" name = "file" id="file"><br><br><br>
         <input type="hidden" name="choice">
         <input type = "button" value ="upload" onClick="checkExistence()">
         <input type="reset" value="Reset">
      </form></center>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <center><b> ${message} </b></center>
   </body>
</html>
```

//controller class

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/fileexists",method = RequestMethod.POST)    

@ResponseBody public String  checkingForDuplicates(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
     String filename=req.getParameter("filename");
     int i=isDuplicate(filename);
     return i+"";
 }
```

Here when i am clicking the button upload , control should go to the function checkExistence() . But it is not moving. Is something wrong with my code ? And i am using

> File f=new File(name);
>   var filename=f.getOriginalFileName();

in javascript function to get the name of the file being uploaded. Does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by making the following corrections.

1. Including jquery plugin
2. changing ajax call url from

   > url: "/FileController/fileexists" 
   >      to
   >   url: "fileexists"
3. In jsp page to get name of the file being uploaded

   var name = $('#file').val();
   File f=new File(name);
   var filename=f.getOriginalFileName();

   > modified :

   var filename=document.getElementById('file').value;

   ```
                   var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
                    if (lastIndex >= 0) {
                  originalfilename = filename.substring(lastIndex +1);
                   }
   ```
4. In controller to get the file name(for checking duplicates)

   > previous :   String filename=req.getParameter("filename");
   >
   > modified :  String filename=req.getParameter("originalfilename");